# Office365 - Push subscription with error The parameter 'Resource' is invalid

Tags: push-notification, office365, office365-apps

I am using following code to perform push subscription, but with this code I am always getting error as invalid resource. Could you please help me on this.  Even i tried resource as "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events"
"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('test@abc.com')/events" but still error pursist. I am doing this rest call from DHC chrome Add in

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
  "Resource": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages",
  "NotificationURL": "https://mywebhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/sample",  
  "ChangeType": "Created, Updated, Deleted",
  "SubscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2016-03-25T08:05:01.9420124Z",
  "ClientState": "samplestate"
}
```

Error:

```
{
"error":{
"code": "ErrorInvalidParameter",
"message": "The parameter 'Resource' is invalid."
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this issue.  Microsoft engineering team is investigating it right now.  Meanwhile, a workaround that worked for multiple subscription cases is to use relative URL for the resource property e.g. 
"Resource": "me/messages",

Thanks.

Comment: Hi,
This is still not working is this issue fixed or still open?

I am able to subscribe using relative url, but please do let us know once we have absolute url working. plus its expected that its should work with Users('test@abc.com')/events but this is failing even in relative url case.

Comment: Hi, I will provide information about the fix when it is available in the service
Would you please provide the exact resource URL you are passing?

This one works
  "Resource": "users('user@tenantdomain.com')/messages",
 "Resource": "users('user@tenantdomain.com')/events",